# Encryption/Decryption with OpenSSL causing different results compared to Mcrypt

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, mcrypt

We replaced Mcrypt with OpenSSL for encrypting and decrypting passwords that are stored in a DB. These are the new functions we are using:

```
function encrypt_openssl_password($key, $pwd)
{
    $cipher="AES-256-CBC";
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes( $ivlen );
    $encrypted = base64_encode(
        $iv .
        openssl_encrypt(
          $pwd,
          $cipher,
          hash('sha256', $key, true),
          OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
          $iv
        )
    );
    return $encrypted;
}
function decrypt_openssl_password($key, $str)
{
    $data = base64_decode($str);
    $cipher="AES-256-CBC";
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = substr($data, 0, $ivlen);
    $decrypted = rtrim(
      openssl_decrypt(
        base64_encode(substr($data, $ivlen)),
        $cipher,
        hash('sha256', $key, true),
        OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,
        $iv),
      "\0"
    );
    return $decrypted;
}
```

**The problem:**

When we decrypt an old password (that was encrypted with Mcrypt) the correct value is returned `string(12) "password2019"` using the new OpenSSL function.

When we now store the exact same password with the new OpenSSL function, we are receiving a wrong value `string(16) "password2019"`

Since decryption of old passwords is working, we assume there is a glitch in the `encrypt_openssl_password` function. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you introduced some multibyte char set in there somehow

Comment: The decrypted string gets 4 `04` bytes added to the decryption if that throws any light on the subject

Comment: Why aren't you using PHP's built-in password handling? Passwords should never ever, not even once, be decryptable. Nope. Nada. Zilch. ***NEVER***

Comment: Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: If I knew that the website I was visiting could decrypt my password I would quit using them @RiggsFolly, no matter how important that site was to me.

Comment: ^^^ Actually that **is the most important point so far**. ^^^ Well that and your previous now amended comment :)

Comment: If you need to migrate an old set of passwords it is relatively easy to develop a migration plan which you can either automate or you can have users create new passwords which are hashed.

Comment: @JayBlanchard because this is a server monitoring application and those passwords need to be decrypted to authenticate with apache in case this particular website is using apache auth.